# How Python validate a regex String for Java?

Tags: java, python, regex

In Pyhton can use `re.compile()` to check regex string, and in Java can use `Pattern.compile()`...

However, my use case is that I have two systems, and need Python to check a string whether is a valid regex string for Java. Is there any packages that can check across language, or ways to convert python regex to java regex, or is it even possible to recognize Java regex in the Python world?

Many thanks

Comment: Crazy that you asked this today, I have the exact same need. I have a Python script that issues queries to Amazon Athena/Presto, which uses Java-style regular expressions.  I'd like to validate the expressions before sending them to Athena.

Comment: Do you have a solution so far? Would be great if you can upvote the question and hope someone experienced to see this

Comment: I think you have to write your own converter in Python. Here is regex class patterns for Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html. Maybe you can implement some kind of lookup table (HashMap) in Pyhon for the converter.

Comment: I have no solution. I doubt there is anything easy that is correct short of writing a fully-fledged parser validator, though that may be easier with the right 3P library.  My likely plan is to just use python's regexp validator, since Python regexps are mostly a subset of what Java supports and just exclude more advanced regexps from being used.

Answer (score 1):

Very late, but I recently encountered this problem. I solved it by using py4j gateway to access `Pattern.compile(regexString)`.

```
from py4j.java_gateway import *
port = launch_gateway()
gateway = JavaGateway(
gateway_parameters=GatewayParameters(port=port), callback_server_parameters=CallbackServerParameters(port=0))
pattern = gateway.jvm.java.util.Pattern
regex_string = "\\K" # will raise an error
pattern.compile(regex_string)
```